# C++ : How to arrange 4 values in an ascending order?

Tags: c++, function

Hello I know it may be a beginners question but I need help.
I need to compare between 4 values added by the user and arrange them in am ascending order by using a function that takes 2 inputs and return the smaller one. I know it can be done by arrays but I must not do it. I already have the function but I don't know how to use to do the trick without having a very long code. Thanks

Comment: Where is the code?

Comment: I cant come up with the code that does this function..

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Look, it just seems like you are looking for someone to do your homework for you, which is strongly frowned upon here. Hence you won't receive any solution here.

Comment: Mostafa. Find smallest and largest. Then keep iterating the whole array till largest reaches the end and smallest reaches the beginning. That's the high abstraction of it. Now, on every iteration, if current index'ed # is less than current indexed+1 #, swap them. And watch out for the last element. Think about it and you will be able to implement it

Comment: I do not even know what has to be done? What form of dataset is allowed? Is it about handcrafting insertionsort?

Comment: simple for loop, if statements and the actual container "whatever it is array, vector.. etc"

Comment: OR. look out for "std::sort" functions that match your container, if you are allowed to use it.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to me to be an *obvious* "homework question," so let me answer it cryptically in order to maybe push you in the right direction.

First, the hint:  **divide and conquer.**

Second hint:  **the "Towers of Hanoi" problem.**

You have a function that can compare *two* values.  Okay, then:  "four elements" can be viewed as "*two* groups of *two* values each."  Given that either of the two input to your comparison-function can be the result obtained by a nested call to the same function . . . you can, indeed, solve this problem, in one line of code, without using arrays.

I'm trying here to "teach you to fish," so I'm not handing you the fish on a platter.

Answer (score 0):

If you know c++ then you can use `sort` function. But for this you have to include `algorithm` as:

```
#include <algorithm>
```

and sort function will be used as:

```
sort(array, array+N);
```

where array is the array name and N is the size of array.After this operation you will get a sorted array in ascending order and return first element.Now the function will look like as:

```
int smallest(int *array) {
    int size = sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]);
    sort(array, array+size);
    return (array[0]);
}
```

And now call this function from `main()`